# Get Smarty variable dynamically

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I have these variables:

```
$idben47    Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "0.00"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root"
$idben48    Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "120.00"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root"
$idben49    Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = "0.00"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root"
```

These variables are assigned here:

```
$this->context->smarty->assign('idben'.$row['id_product_attribute'], $combinations[$row['id_product_attribute']]['unit_impact']);
```

How I can dynamically get these in my tpl file?

In my tpl file I already have the $id_attribute variable (47,48,49 in this case).
I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<span>Prezzo:{$idben.id_attribute}</span>
```

But the system don't get the variable...

Thank you in advance

Comment: `id_attribute` is a property of `$idben`?

Comment: Are you trying to get the value? If so, you should add "->value" after either solution. (It doesn't make much sense to print out a smarty object directly.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed to change the `$idbenxy` variables, you can put them in arrays instead.

```
// PHP
$idben = array($idben0, $idben1, ... , $idben49);
// HTML
<span>Prezzo:{$idben[$id_attribute]}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

I don't have a PHP installation on hand, but I think `${'idben'.$id_attribute}` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

use cat:

```
{${'idben'|cat:$id_attribute}}
```

if you're going to use the values inside the variable more than once, and for clarity in your template, instead of composing the variable name each time you need a value, you can create a new temporal variable within the loop (or whatever) that uses it:

```
{$curridben= ${'idben'|cat:$id_attribute}}
```

and then just

```
<span>Prezzo:{$curridben.value}</span>
```

Comment: Using: 
${'idben'|cat:$id_attribute}

The result is this:
$idben21

It's not getting the variable but only print it

Comment: yes, sorry, you have to use it between brackets {${'idben'|cat:$id_attribute}}

Comment: Solution1:{${'idben'|cat:$id_attribute}} [blank]
           Solution2:{${'idben'|cat:48}} [works like I want]

Comment: maybe the id_attribute value is empty or is an array?

Comment: as you can see from my previous comment if i use the number it works, If I use the dynamic id it doesn't....